# pySerial XON/OFF fails on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, flow-control

I have a small loop that is supposed to read some text data of multiple lines and unspecified length (sometimes rather large) from the serial port, and write it to a file:

```
while True:
    data = port.readline()
    file.write(data)
    if not data:
    break
```

I have the port setup correctly and the whole program works beautifully on a windows machine.  When I run it on a Linux box it still receives the data but the software flow control fails to work - instead the control codes for the `XON` and `XOFF` (\S and \Q) are actually being written to the file.  Causing overrun errors and destroying my data.
I've read and tried everything I can think of - it seems most examples of this are only expecting a few bytes and aren't using any flow control.  I have also tried the `miniterm` that is included with `pySerial` and it gives the same results.

Any ideas?

Added lines for file and port:

```
file = open('temp.txt', 'ab') #Open the temporary file to append the incoming data to.
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1, xonxoff=1, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0)
```

There isn't much more to it than that except that I write a string to the other device to start sending, which works since I'm seeing the response back with the data.  I've also tried printing to the console rather than writing the file.  Same thing - overruns and printed control codes.

Update:  I have also tried reading a single byte at a time instead of the whole line and have tried other baud rates - all with no change.

Update#2:  Have been doing some reading and testing.  Tested with minicom. Same results.  Manually verified that port was set properly with 'stty -a' (although I don't trust this as it may save and restore the settings according to something I read).  It's possibly a problem in termios?

Comment: Can I see the rest of the code? I'd like to know exactly what port and file are.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing unprintables characters from your received data.

```
data = data.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try using this serial capture code. it has a Pyserial approach also but it is simplified. There is a split formula for the newline that may help with the flow control if you change it to meet your needs.

https://github.com/DaDaDadeo/Batch-Capture/blob/master/serial_to_tcp.py